# How to make live reload using cordova and vue without using npm build

Tags: cordova, vuejs2

I am using this command to open up my app in the browser: cordova run browser but it does not refresh itself when I update my code. How can I do that?

Every time i need to build application for checking in browser.

I am also try with :
npm i cordova-plugin-browsersync.
But not working.